# What happens when EC2 ubuntu instance is shutdown?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu based EC2 instance. I have tomcat installed on this instance and I did a mistake while shutting down Tomcat.

I was trying to execute `shutdown.sh` present in `tomcat/bin` directory but by mistake I executed OS level `sudo shutdown now` command and entire EC2 instance got shutdown.

I checked into AWS console and in AWS console I can see that instance is still in `Running` state but I am not able to connect to this instance through putty. It's been more than 12 hours since I accidentally shutdown that instance but AWS console is still showing it in `Running` state.

I am wondering if I will lose all of my data present in that EC2 instance and how to restart such a instance?

---

**UPDATE:**

I solved the issue by just restarting the instance through AWS console. After reboot, everything started working fine and great thing is that **** I didn't lose any data  ****

I found this interesting thread on AWS forum in which the other guy did the same thing. Here is the URL of that thread. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=70306

Hope it will someone's time some day in future :)

Thanks,

Chandrashekhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ec2 instance is not EBS backed, then shutting it down it will lose any data on the instance. EBS backed instances don't lose their instance storage when they crash or are shut down.

Instance store ec2's cannot be stopped - they can only be rebooted or terminated. Once you gave it a shutdown command, it would not be able to do anything but terminate, since it cannot go into a stopped state.

You will most likely have to terminate the instance from the console, but the AWS discussion forums may have another solution for you.

Comment: Any idea why AWS console is still showing this instance as 'Running'? Its been more than 12 hours since I shutdown instance but AWS console is still showing it as 'Running'

Comment: @Shekhar I'm guessing running the shutdown command does not fire off any aws specific events that handle shutdown. According to this [thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/343004/shutting-an-ec2-instance-down-locally-on-the-instance), you must configure instances to shutdown completely when running `sudo shutdown now`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you refresh the dashboard? It's probably stopped.

If it's EBS backed then you won't lose your data as long it was stored on an EBS mount. If it isn't, it's history.

Comment: Yes I refreshed the dashboard but even after refreshing couple of times instance was green and was in 'Running' state.

Comment: Then I'd reboot it in the dashboard and bring it back up. Perhaps it is hung up stopping. You can also try creating an AMI image from it with the No Reboot checked and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm checking if EBS volume is attached to this instance. I am new to AWS world so googling many things about 'how to do xxx on aws'.